# Как получить имя ресурса через интерфейс onItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

У меня есть `GridView`, в нем несколько изображений. С помощью `OnItemClickListener` и метода `onItemClick()` я могу получить `position` кликнутого элемента, но мне это не очень подходит, потому что один элемент может находиться в разных местах. Как мне получить имя ресурса кликнутого элемента через `View`?

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        int position, long id) {
        //тут нужно получить имя ресурса
    }
});
```

Comment: Как раз-таки position передает индекс кликнутого элемента в списке. Зная индекс, доставайте нужный объект из массива.

Comment: имя файла кликнутого изображения?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Можно и так, но мне интересно можно ли имя ресурса получить.

Comment: @pavlofff да, если это возможно

Comment: или все же идинтификатор `R.drawable.imageN` ?

Comment: @pavlofff Идентификатор тоже подойдет. imageN - это же и есть имя файла, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: да, `imageN` - имя файла, но значение `R.drawable.imageN` - уникальное число, идентификатор за которым закреплен данный файл

Comment: Так могу я получить через View идентификатор?

Comment: Да, можете. Но никто не знает, как вы используете этот идентификатор. И соответственно, гле его взять - тоже никому не известно. Покажите больше кода.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо из `View` все же нельзя получить ID ресурса, который находится в этом `View` прямым способом (через методы самого `View`).

Можно при присвоении `View` значения ресурса, записывать это значение в тег:

```
 imageView.setImageResource( R.drawable.imageN);
 imageView.setTag(R.drawable.imageN);
```

Затем вы можете получить это значение из того `View`, что передает колбэк:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
         int id = v.getTag();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В адаптере заведите (хотя уже наверное завели) массив/список файлов/ID файлов картинок кои отображаете.
2. В методе отрисовки элемента, в адаптере, из этого массива/списка картинки отображаете по позиции в адаптере.
3. В `setOnItemClickListener` получите свой адаптер и свой список/массив из него.

   ```
   final gridview = ....;
   gridview.setAdapter(....);
   gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
       {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
              {
                   YOURS_ADAPTER_CLASS adapter = (YOURS_ADAPTER_CLASS) gridview.getAdapter();
                   int[] arrayOfImagesAdresses = adapter.NAME_OF_VAR_FROM_FIRST_POINT;
                   int adressOfCurrentImage = arrayOfImagesAdresses[position];
              }
       });
   ```